# How to allow a wildcard for part of a querystring in IIS request filtering

Tags: security, iis-7.5, wildcard

I have a querystring that is made up of 3 parts.

The first 2 parts are static but the last one is dynamic and can be any value.

Because keywords used in part of the querystring are blocked / denied by IIS I need to know how to allow a dynamic value for only the last part of the query string in Request Filtering in IIS 7.5

So for example:

in-content=knownvalue&out-content=knownwvalue&searchable=  *this could be any word that is made up of characters, numbers, hyphens apostrophe's & signs etc.

Thanks in advance for any help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because keywords used in part of the querystring are blocked / denied by IIS I need to know how to allow a dynamic value for only the last part of the query string

I don't believe you can configure the default Request Validation on a per-parameter level at present, so to allow all input for a particular parameter you'd have to disable it.

(I would do that anyway because IIS Request Validation is a misguided [bogus security measure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511056/18936) that [hides not solves](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38082) injection problems.)

If you still wanted to do input filtering on a parameter-by-parameter basis afterwards, you could implement that in the application or by providing your own request validation (subclassing RequestValidation and pointing `requestValidationType` at that class). Application-specific input filtering is generally a good thing, but it is not the answer to injection XSS issues, for which the only effective solution remains correct escaping for the output context.

Comment: Thanks bobince. I suspected it wasn't possible to configure at the parameter level. I've escaped the input as well as added filters on the server side to remove the most offending verbs...so...now I will test a little and we'll see if it maintains at least a level of security. Thanks again for the clear response.